# On properties of time-evolution operator in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices

I found some [handouts](https://www.oulu.fi/tf/kvmIII/english/2004/03_timeoper.pdf) on the subject, but I am in doubt about the following

**Composition property**. The evolution from the time $t_0$ to a later time $t_2$ should be equivalent to the evolution from the initial time $t_0$ to an intermediate time $t_1$ followed by the evolution from $t_1$ to the final time $t_2$, i.e.
$$U(t_2, t_0) = U(t_2, t_1)U(t_1, t_0) \qquad (t_2 > t_1 > t_0)$$

Is this *always* true, even for a time-dependent Hamiltonian $\hat H(t)$?

Comment: Yes, this is a property that we want to enforce on such a quantity that we want to label as time evolution (the semigroup property - which corresponds exactly to the concept of flows on phase space in ODEs and classical mechanics). However, the details of actually computing such a time evolution operator when the Hamiltonian does not commute with itself at later times is quite hairy and is often denoted with a simple "time ordering" operator and tucked away - look up Dyson series for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always true. If you evolve a state vector $v$ present at time $t_0$ to a later time $t_1$, then you'll have
$$
               U(t_1,t_0)v
$$
Then, if you evolve that vector state from $t_1$ to $t_2$, then you'll have
$$
              U(t_2,t_1)U(t_1,t_0)v,
$$
which had better be the same as evolving $v$ from $t_0$ to $t_2$:
$$
           U(t_2,t_0)v = U(t_2,t_1)U(t_1,t_0)v
$$
Time evolution has this 'exponential' property. If the system is time independent, then the evolution depends only on the difference between times, and that is a straight exponential property:
$$
             U(t_2-t_1)U(t_1-t_0)=U(t_2-t_0).
$$

Comment: I can't say though that $U(t_2,t_0)=U(t_2,t_1)U(t_1,t_0)$ is the same as $U(t_1,t_0)U(t_2,t_1)$, right? Is there a case in which they commute?

Comment: @ric.san : If you evolve the state of the system from $t_0$ to $t_1$ and then evolve that state from $t_1$ to $t_2$, the result is the same as evolving the original state from $t_0$ to $t_2$. That's the way the World works.